# Proof that the set $\left\{ {\cos \left( {\frac{{n\pi x}}{L}} \right)} \right\}_{n\,\, = \,\,0}^\infty$ is orthogonal

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

I'm looking at example 1 from [this page](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/PeriodicOrthogonal.aspx), which reads

> Show that $\left\{ {\cos \left( {\frac{{n\pi x}}{L}} \right)} \right\}_{n\,\, = \,\,0}^\infty$ is mutually orthogonal on $- L \le x \le L$.

The author gives a lengthy proof that uses the evenness of cosine to work with the integral from $0$ to $L$ instead. But I think I've found a simpler approach.

If we can show that

$\int_{{ - L}}^{L}{{\cos \left( {\frac{{n\pi x}}{L}} \right)\cos \left( {\frac{{m\pi x}}{L}} \right)\,dx}} = 0$

for all $m \ne n$, then we know that the set is mutually orthogonal.

By a trig identity, the above equals

$\frac{1}{2}\int_{{ - L}}^{L}{{\cos \left({(n-m)\frac{{\pi x}}{L}} \right)+\cos \left( {(n+m)\frac{{\pi x}}{L}} \right)\,dx}}$

$= \frac{1}{2}\int_{{ - L}}^{L}{{\cos \left({(n-m)\frac{{\pi x}}{L}} \right)\,dx}}+\frac{1}{2}\int_{{ - L}}^{L}{{\cos \left( {(n+m)\frac{{\pi x}}{L}} \right)\,dx}}$

Since cosine is an even function, each of these integrals evaluates to zero.

Is this reasoning sound?

Comment: Looks fine to me. Also, just plug in $m=n$, and then the integrand is always positive. And treat $n=m=0$ case separately, same as in the example.

Comment: "Since cosine is an even function, each of these integrals evaluates to zero." I'd check that reasoning again. If $m = n$, then this is not true!

Comment: The integral of an even integrable function over symmetric limits is NOT $0$ in general.  The integral of an odd integrable function over symmetric limits is $0$.

Comment: Thank you. @MarkViola's point is right--I confused the properties of odd and even functions. (But for integer m and n, I think my argument still holds true since the limits are the periods of the function?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your argument is not correct as already pointed out in the comments.
$\int_{-L}^{L} \cos((n-m)\frac  {\pi x} L)dx= [\sin ((n-m)\frac  {\pi x} L))]/[n-m)\frac  {\pi } L)]_{-L}^{L}=0$ since $\sin (k\pi)=0$ for $k=n-m$ as well as for $k=m-n$. Similarly the second integral is also $0$.